# How to use svg image file in XAML Image component

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I am trying to use svg to display an illustration on uwp app. I am creating BitmapImage object using svg like below

```
m_imageSource = Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage(Windows::Foundation::Uri{ GetFilePath() + L"FamilyValueProp\\Assets\\Images\\family_promo.svg"});
```

And setting this source to Image component

```
<Image x:Name="PromoImage" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

But this does not render the image. Image is present in the path that is provided to BitmapImage object. Not sure what is going wrong. Any help please?

Comment: @shawan Kendrot 's answer should work, you could check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [SvgImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource?view=winrt-22000) if creating an ImageSource.

```
m_imageSource = new SvgImageSource(new Uri("mySvgImage.svg"));
```

You can also set the svg directly to the Image

```
<Image Source="Assets/mysvg.svg"/>
```

Note that animations are not supported

> SvgImageSource supports secure static mode from the SVG specification and does not support animations or interactions